# ExtJS combobox autocomplete hitting store's URL

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a combobox on a view. I am loading data from store. The code for combobox is as follows:

```
xtype: 'combobox',
fieldLabel: 'Department',
store: Ext.create('UGCApp.store.Department'),
emptyText: 'Select Department',
allowBlank: false,
name: 'departmentId',
displayField: 'departmentName',
valueField: 'departmentId',
flex: 1,
queryMode: 'local'
```

This is the code for the store:

```
Ext.define('UGCApp.store.Department', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: "departmentlist",
    model: 'UGCApp.model.Department',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'localhost/UGCApplication/api/getdepartmentlist',
        method: 'GET'
    }
});
```

The issue is when I type anything inside the combobox. It is supposed to get the list from the available records from the store. Instead of this behavior, whenever I type a letter, the store's URL is hit and it generates an error at the server side. I need to load the data inside the combobox from store and whenever any letter or word is typed the autocomplete should search the data from the loaded store locally. It should not hit the server.

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: I don't want to hit back store's URL when the user types in the combobox since the data is already in the store. The autocomplete should search the local data instead of hitting the server.

Comment: Looks reasonable. `queryMode: 'local'` should do the job. Can you post a runnable test case?

Comment: No sir. I am afraid I don't have an idea about test cases in ExtJS.